# Querying distinct results in graylog2

Tags: graylog2

Is there a way to do a search in graylog2 and only return distinct results for a given field?  What I'm trying to accomplish is a stream or dashboard widget that will give me the number of IIS errors from distinct ip addresses.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to

- extract the ip address as a field (ip_address),
- search for IIS errors
- In the search results message fields, on the right, use ip_address "quick values" to get the count of errors for a specific ip address

Answer (score 0):

the approach to see the distribution of count-of-errors per ip via "quick values" is good. For a hint how to go about uniqueness/distinct ip addresses or any value, "card()" for cardinality can be used in graylog. But aggregation can be done in other ways.

To get the number of errors-per-ip in a Data Table, just add the rows and do a count() over them and restrict the search query to http_response:>=500
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use aggregating count by unique field like request id or your values

Answer (score -1):

If it's a field, then "IpAddress:111.111.111.1" would search for all logs with 111.111.111.1 as the ip address.

Comment: this q is about _distinct_ values